# How to display post summary on index page using Jekyll?

Tags: html, markdown, jekyll

I am using [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to create a blog by following this excellent [tutorial](http://www.andrewmunsell.com/tutorials/jekyll-by-example/). I would like to add a post summary on the index page. I tried using:

> post.content | truncatewords:50 | strip_html

it works but it displays the entire post until the 50 word count is reached. This includes the heading too. I would like to just summarize the actual content of the post. How can I structure my posts to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [YAML front matter](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll/wiki/YAML-Front-Matter) and define a separate title per post, like this:

```
---
title: Efficient smuflet based kwoxel trees
---

Post content goes here.
```

Then you can use or not use `post.title` as you please.

Or, if you want to write a separate summary (not just the first n characters) for each post, just add a field for that summary in the front matter as well.

Comment: Nice idea about a summary field.It is more flexible to add a summary myself than truncating the existing post.I should try that out.

Comment: Latest beta version has better support for excerpts.

Answer (score 36):

### Update 16 Nov, 2015

Now Jekyll support excerpt separator, In template you can do this:

```
{% if post.excerpt %}
    {{ post.excerpt }}
{% endif %}
```

and In global config `_config.yml` you can set:

```
excerpt_separator: <!--more-->
```

and the same use with `<!--more-->` html comment tag.

### Old answer

You can try this:

```
{% if post.content contains '<!--more-->' %}
  {{ post.content | split:'<!--more-->' | first }}
{% else %}
  {{ post.content }}
{% endif %}
```

and add `<!--more-->` tag in the article after summary, just like Wordpress.

Comment: It's better to combile all above solutions: {% else %} {{ post.content | truncatewords:50 | strip_html }} {% endif %}

Answer (score 5):

From the Jekyll documentation:

> Each post automatically takes the first block of text, from the beginning of the content to the first occurrence of excerpt_separator, and sets it as the post.excerpt.
>
> ...
>
> Because Jekyll grabs the first paragraph you will not need to wrap the excerpt in p tags, which is already done for you.

See http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts for more info and an example.

Comment: The link really helped! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use `{{ post.excerpt }}` in your `index.md` file to get an excerpt of this post.